# jQuery: adding tooltips to parts of text in a textarea, and removing them when user starts editing it

Tags: jquery, textarea, spell-checking

I am planning on building a tool that will provide suggestions to the user on his text, similar to a spellchecker.

I would like to:

- highlight problematic text
- remove the highlighting when the user starts editing it.

How would I do this in jquery? Highlighting problematic text looks easy, even adding tooltips with a lib like qtip2, but how would I remove that highlighting as soon as the user starts to edit the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to remove something assign a handler to textarea's `change`, `focus`, `mousedown`, `keydown` events